# Animation with a centred div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple layout, a larger div within a smaller div, which I want to animate:

```
<div style="
        position: relative;
        left:100px;
        width:200px;
        height:400px;
        background:red;
        overflow:visible"
>
    <div id="stamp" style="
            position:absolute;
            margin: 0 auto;
            bottom:-150px;
            width:200%;
            height:150px;
            background:blue"
    ></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#stamp").animate({
    bottom: "200",
    width: "150%"
}, 400, function() {
    $("#stamp").animate({
        width: '80%', 
    }, 220, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7metw85n)

What I want, but can't figure out is, I want the blue div to be centered, rather than left aligned.

So the blue div will start centered, will animated up (still centered), then after the animation the blue div will be centered at 80% width.

Comment: Your code is fine to an extent. All you need is to add left: 1%; right: 1% to the #stamp div - [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/7metw85n/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/7metw85n/9/)

Answer (score 1):

So in the end blue div will have 80% width. Why not add margin left to the blue div.

```
margin-left:10%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7metw85n/2/)

Comment: The idea is that the blue div will be centered at all times, not just at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `margin: 0 auto` won't have the desired effect (centering) anymore if the element in question is positioned absolutely.

To achieve what you want, I'd ditch `position: absolute` and just work with a negative margin (which needs to be animated as well to keep the centering):

```js
$("#stamp").animate
({
    bottom: "200",
    width: "150%",
    marginLeft: "-75%"
   
}, 400,
    function()
    {
        $( "#stamp" ).animate
        ({
            width: "80%",
            marginLeft: "-40%"
   
        }, 220, function() { /* complete */ });
});
```

```css
#container
{
    position: relative;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background:red;
    overflow:visible;    
}
#stamp
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    bottom:-150px;
    width:200%;
    height:150px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="stamp"></div>
</div>
```

(Also on http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/g7vtbjns/)

Answer (score 0):

For centered div change your css

```
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
  bottom: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Now you will have centered div within red div

Check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7metw85n/1/

Comment: This won't work will it? By removing the absolute positioning only the width animation will work? Th idea is the blue div will almost fly in, but be centered at all times.